# I can't load data from json and I'm using backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to load content to the page and not charge me, maybe problem with views, because the data obtained by the model if I work.
backbonejs not know much about, I'm looking to work with JSON example to display content on a website.

could you help me, please?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {  

            var Article = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var ArticleList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Article,
                url: 'https://support.mozilla.org/en/search?topics=hot&a=1&w=1&format=json&callback=?',
                parse: function(response) {
                    return response.results;
                }
            });               


            var articleView = Backbone.View.extend({
                initialize: function(){
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function(){                        
                    var tmpl = _.template( $("#articleTemplate").html(), {} );
                    var html = template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON());                       
                    this.$el.html( html );
                }
            });


            var articles = new ArticleList();

            var articlesView = new articleView({model: articles});

            articles.fetch();

            articles.bind('reset', function() {                   
               articlesView.render();
            });                

        });
    </script>
    <title>Fortified Studio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="articles"></div>


    <script id="articleTemplate" type="text/template">

        <div class="results">
            <div class="search_summary">
                <%= search_summary %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You will get better results if you ask specific questions that have specific answers.  Also, try to mention what you think should happen, what really happened, etc.  This will help people understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of mistakes in your code. See comments in the (working) code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function() {  

        var Article = Backbone.Model.extend();

        var ArticleList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Article,
            url: 'https://support.mozilla.org/en/search?topics=hot&a=1&w=1&format=json&callback=?',
            parse: function(response) {
                return response.results;
            }
        });               


        var articleView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
               // You haven't fetched your collection yet. So don't render. 
               //this.render();
            },
            render: function(){                        
                // Underscore.js template assumes data is sent into _.template(...)
                // You store a Collection of Models in this.model. Hence, wrap the Collection json into one json "results" attribute.
                var html = _.template( $("#articleTemplate").html(), {results: this.model.toJSON()} );
                //var html = template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON());                       
                this.$el.html( html );
                return this;
            }
        });


        var articles = new ArticleList();

        var articlesView = new articleView({model: articles});


        // Bind to the reset event before fetching. Fetch will raise "reset" event.
        // The render function should return this, and hence, you can use $el and append it to #articles.
        articles.bind('reset', function() {                   
           $("#articles").append(articlesView.render().$el);
        }); 

        // everything is wired up. Now fetch, will will start a chain reaction, i.e. render the view, and append to #articles
        articles.fetch();               

    });
</script>
<title>Fortified Studio</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="articles"></div>


<script id="articleTemplate" type="text/template">

    <div class="results">
        <div class="search_summary">
            <ul>
            <% _.each(results, function(res) { %> <li><%= res.search_summary %></li> <% }); %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this example is usefull for me :D